# SPFx Field Customizer: Customization does not appear if document library is is within a webPart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I finally made my field customizer work in SharePoint online. It provides a URL field with modified link based on other item metadata.

It creates a custom view which shows the new column provided by the field costomizer.

It works fine on the main page of the library, but when I add a web part with the library to display it on a modern web page together with other stuff, the column stays empty.

Is it by design, is there a trick or is it a bug?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a known issue.

SPFx field customizer and JSON column formatting, both,  wont work currently in the modern list and library view webparts.

MS is aware of the issue and Vesa Juvonen, PM of the SharePoint team mentioned sometime back, that they are looking to fix it. Whenever an update is pushed out, no ETA , then these will start working in the webparts. If you notice though, the list and library webparts are still in preview, its annoying but have to live with it :)

Reference - [SPFX field customizer should also work in the list webpart](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2105)

UserVoice - [Support column formatting in list/library webparts](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/32872726-column-formatting-in-list-web-part)

Comment: Looks like after so much time it is still not working... After adding the webpart (library view) to the page field customizer is working but after refreshing the page it vanishes. In the console, there is an error that manifest cannot be found (even though it was working before page refresh...)